# PreparedStatement return getUpdateCount() = -1

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

When we use the executeUpdate () method can not insert instructions to return ResultSet, such as a SELECT. I happen to have an update which to start a trigger, and the trigger have a command "Select * from table".

I could solve the problem by assigning this command to a variable as an example: "Select * from table " soon resultSet would be no problem for the JDBC executeUpdate.

The problem is that the system can work with triggers other integrated systems that have no domain and I can not change, so the option was to use the run command (), which as shown in the code image can I check if the return is a ResultSet ( return true). In the statement while discarding ResultSets generated in the trigger and getMoreResults returns me the number of rows affected by the Update, in the case of the frame in blue, using the statement returns the value 3, which is correct.

The problem is to use the PreparedStatement (red frame), where getUpdateCount is returning -1, but should return 3, which is the number of rows affected in the UPDATE.

Problem occurs in SQL Server 2012 database or 2008, it was not simulated with Oracle

Follows the code example with the existing trigger on the table that I'm doing update

I wonder if anyone knows why the return is different for getMoreResults.

[Code Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5Q9s.png)

[Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep2xg.png)

```
public class TestarConexao {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:magnus;user=rh;password=rh;MARS_Connection=yes;", "rh", "rhk");

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        boolean is = stmt.execute("update Usu_teste set usu_codigo = 1 where usu_codigo = 1");

        while (is) {
            System.out.println("There is ResultSet: " + is);
            is = stmt.getMoreResults();
        }
        System.out.println("UpdateCount with Statement: " + stmt.getUpdateCount());

        PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement("update Usu_teste set usu_codigo = 1 where usu_codigo = 1");
        boolean isPrep = prepStmt.execute();
        while (isPrep){
            System.out.println("There is ResultSet: " + isPrep);
            isPrep = prepStmt.getMoreResults();
        }

        System.out.println("UpdateCount with PreparedStatement: " +prepStmt.getUpdateCount());
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice that you are using Java's JDBC-ODBC Bridge, which has a reputation for being buggy. Have you tried using Microsoft's JDBC driver for SQL Server to see if it behaves differently?

Comment: the application was developed with java. I'm not testing just one example.